# Selecting and grouping on ranges

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some data like this:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | height | width |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 |   1000 |   300 |
|  2 |   1024 |   330 |
|  3 |    600 |   200 |
|  4 |    624 |   311 |
|  5 |    724 |   511 |
|  6 |    300 |   200 |
+----+--------+-------+
```

with many more rows.

I'd like to run a query that does something like this:

```
Count how many rows have a height between 0 and 400, between 401 and 600, between 601 and 1000, and 1000+
```

In this case, I'd want it to return something like this:

```
+-------+---------+----------+-------+
| 0-400 | 401-600 | 601-1000 | 1000+ |
+-------+---------+----------+-------+
|     1 |       1 |        3 |     1 |
+-------+---------+----------+-------+
```

I'm going to hard code the ranges.

Currently, I'm planning to run a query for each range, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select sum(if(height<400,1,0)) '<400', sum(if(height>=400 and height<600,1,0)) '400-600'...
```

g

Comment: Thanks, knew it had to be easy!

Comment: @RichBradshaw: It can actually be even easier. In MySQL, booleans are converted to integers implicitly in most, if not all, contexts. So, you can use your boolean expressions directly as the arguments of the `SUM`s: `SUM(height BETWEEN 0 AND 400)`, `SUM(height > 1000)` etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
select  sum(case when height between 0 and 400 then 1 end) as [0-400]
,       sum(case when height between 401 and 600 then 1 end) as [401-600]
,       ...
from    YourTable
```